# Parsing JS JSONs array as a Kotlin array

Tags: arrays, json, kotlin

I need to gather some data from an API from my Kotlin app and I need to parse a JSONs array from JS in a Kotlin array. This is the code that I'm using to do request to the API:

```
URL(apiUrl).readText()
```

And the output is something like this:

```
[{"id":5,"name":"Test1","ip":"192.168.0.1","port":10302,"id_slave":1},{"id":6,"name":"Test2","ip":"192.168.1.1","port":502,"id_slave":1}]
```

There's anyway to parse that string as a Kotlin array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: Not really, cause this is not just a JSON, is an array of JSONs in String format

Comment: You should first read about JSON format and figure out that JSON can contain  array at top-level and it's absolutely valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You output seems like it is a JSONArray. You can use Gson library to change your JSONArray to Kotlin Array.

implement gson library in gradel:

**implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'**

kotlin code:

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
val ModelArray= gson.fromJson(body,Array<YourDataModel>::class.java).toList()
```